# Process and Task in Android

Tags: android

Can someone let me know what is the difference between process and task in android.
As far as I understand whenever you lanuch an application, it will run in a seperate process. Am I Right? 
An application can contain multiple activities which can be run in same or different process. 
A Task is a set of activities (orederly). 
A process can contain multiple tasks. 
Please differentiate the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Process is a low-level concept. It basically groups the threads started in your application (amongst which, the UI thread).
2. Task is a high-level concept. It is a group of activities with a logical link between them (a use-case scenario for instance)

Roughly : your application tasks will be made of activities presented to the user, which will imply running one or more threads to do the work they are designed to do, which will run within your application process.